# JackSon with ormlite exception objectcache

Tags: android, json, jackson, ormlite

I use Jackson to read a file with json format and put results inside an ormlite database but when I read objects I get an exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "objectCache": com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao#setObjectCache(1 params) vs com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao#setObjectCache(1 params)

I have a class to declare ormlite and jackson propierties:

```
@DatabaseTable
@JsonDeserialize
public final class Items extends BaseDaoEnabled<Items, String> implements Serializable{
@DatabaseField (canBeNull = false, id = true, width = 10)
private String item = "";

@DatabaseField (canBeNull = true, dataType = DataType.BIG_DECIMAL)
@JsonIgnore
private BigDecimal dto = BigDecimal.ZERO;

@JsonIgnore
@ForeignCollectionField (eager = false)
private ForeignCollection<Group> groups = null;

@DatabaseField (canBeNull = true,  foreign = true)
@JsonIgnore
transient private Price price = null;

@JsonCreator
public Items(@JsonProperty("items") String items) {
    this.items = items;
}

@JsonIgnore
public Items(String item) {
this.item = item;
}
}
```

Add Json file is: [{"item":"AAAAAA"},{"item": "BBBBBB"}]
I tried different options such as

```
@JsonIgnore //in class properties

ObjectMapper object = new ObjectMapper();
object.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

But neither option solve the problem. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you declare the objects using Jackson tags and OrmLite tags also? Post your object and your Json element to better understand the issue.

Comment: I have edited my question, I have added tags.

Comment: Since your object is extending another `BaseDaoEnabled<Items, String>`, maybe it is not such a good idea to use it for both `OrmLite` and `Jackson` (you have methods there that are not ignored by `Jackson`). Better create a separate Jackson dedicated and once the json translated copy the values to `OrmLite` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new class to interpret Json (ItemsJson.class) and Insert or Update the element in the JsonCreator such as:

```
@JsonCreator
public ItemsJson(@JsonProperty("item") String item, @JsonProperty("groups") String groups) {

    if(item != null){
        try {
        OpenHelper helper = OpenHelper.getHelper(getContext());
        Dao<Items, String> daoItems = helper.getDao(Items.class);

        Items itemAux = new Items(item);        
        daoItems.refresh(itemAux);

            if(groups != null){
                Dao<Groups, String> daoGroups = helper.getDao(Groups.class);
                Groups groupsAux = new Groups(groups) ;
                daoGroups.createIfNotExists(groupsAux);
                daoGroups.refresh(groupsAux);
                itemAux.setGroups(groupsAux);
            }

          daoItems.createOrUpdate(itemAux);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } 



}
```